# mouse : disable right and middle button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used this but it doesn't work; no errors in the firebug:

```
$("div").live('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     return ;
   }if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     return false;
   }else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      return false; 
   }
})
```

I can disable right click with `contextmenu` but I dont know what to do about middle button.

Comment: If you are using jquery latest version then use `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: According to [this page](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html), "Firefox and Opera [as of Aug '11] have default actions associated with middle mouse buttons that cannot be disabled from Javascript".

Comment: If you're using jQuery >= 1.4.2 then use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with Javascript and/or an HTML attribute (which is really a Javascript event handler anyway) as [described here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Disabling_the_right_click.aspx)

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(e)
{
   if (e.button == 2) {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</body>
```

That being said: DON'T DO IT.

Why? Because it achieves nothing other than annoying users. Also many browsers have a security option to disallow disabling of the right click (context) menu anyway.

Not sure why you'd want to. If it's out of some misplaced belief that you can protect your source code or images that way, think again: you can't.

Comment: Your answer only seems to cover the right-click, but the question said _"I can disable right click with contextmenu but I dont know what to do about middle button."_

Answer (score 1):

You missed an 'else' in your code.

```
$("div").live('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     return ;
   }else if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     return false;
   }else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      return false; 
   }
})
```

Comment: It wouldn't really matter, as the code has a `return` statement in the `if` body.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this below piece of code to disable right and middle mouse button click.

```js
 //Disable the right mouse button click.
 document.oncontextmenu = function () {
    return false;
 };
 //Disable the middle mouse button click.
 document.onauxclick = function () {
    return false;
 };
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```