# Disable middle mouse click

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent

I need your help in one question that how to disable the middle mouse click on any link to open a new tab  in IE 7,8,9.
I have tried many thing like

```
return false;
e.cancelBubble = true;e.returnValue = false;
```

But not able to stop that feature of IE to open New tab.But if i am putting alert message e

```
if (event.button == 4)
    {
alert("shashank");
}
```

I am able to stop to open new tab .But I don't want to use alert message.

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498092/mouse-disable-right-and-middle-button-click

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392318/how-to-disable-the-mouse-wheel-click-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 2 ){
       alert("middle click");    
       return false; // Or e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLfQ/21/)

Comment: You may have forgotten the brakets `{}`? :)

Comment: Whoops.. Thank you..Updated :)

Comment: Hi I have use same code but it is not working with IE 9 on click of middle button its opening a new tab...                                                   <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">go google</a>

<script>
 $(document).mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 2 ){
       alert("middle click");    
       return false; // Or e.preventDefault()
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers above worked for me. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) the `auxclick` event is the proper way to do this.

The following code will prevent the middle click behaviour on the entire page.

```
window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
  if (event.button === 1) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: came here looking for an angular solution, this works, for any future readers, I placed in `ngOnInit()` in `app.component.ts`